# Get the size of the file in MB having only digits in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to get the size of the file in MB and need to have only digits in the output in linux.

Below is what I've tried

`ls -l --b=M  test.csv | cut -d " " -f5`

Output I'm getting as 91M but I need the output as 91 only.

`stat -c %s test.csv`

Output is `94567551` which is in bytes but I want the size to be displayed in MB

Comment: Try the `du -m` command. `man du` will give you more info

Comment: I'm getting the file size in number and also getting the file name @moo. But I need only the number

Comment: Why don't you convert 94567551 into the exact MB value then? When doing this, you need to decided what exactly a MB would be: Is it 1000000 byte or 1024*1024 byte? Bothe conventions are in common use.

Comment: `du -m | awk '{ print $1 }'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

linux probably has `stat`.

```
echo $(( $(stat -c %s test.csv)/1024/1024 ))
```

Alternatively, `du -k` is portable.

```
( read k _ < <(du -k test.csv) && echo $(( k/1024 )) )
```

Without the process redirection bash-ism:

```
du -k test.csv | ( read k _ && expr $k / 1024 )
```

Comment: When I store this `$(( $(stat -c %s test.csv)/1024/1024 ))` in a variable I'm getting a error. syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/1024/1024 ")

Comment: that means `$(stat -c %s test.csv)` didn't return a number, so the shell is seeing `$(( /1024/1024 ))` which is not a valid arithmetic expression. you can run with `set -vx` to see what is happening

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

```
read n < <(stat -c %s file)
bc <<< "scale=0; $n/1024/1024"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we just use `sed` ?

```
ls -l --b=M fileOfMy | sed -n 's/.* \([0-9]\+[KMGTPEZY]\) .*/\1/p
```

Comment: Thanks to [**not** parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I didn' know that , thanks for information

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
stat -c %s test.csv | awk '{ printf "%.0f", $1 / 1024 / 1024 }'
```

OR

```
block_size=$(getconf PAGESIZE)
file_size=$(wc -c < test.csv)
mb_size=$((file_size / (1024 * block_size)))
echo $mb_size
```

OR

```
ls -l --block-size=1M test.csv | awk '{ size=$5/1024; if (size>=1) printf "%.0f\n", size; else printf "0\n" }'
```

Comment: Thanks to [**not** parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)